# Alarm Manager does not work Android Java

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am developing simple reminder using Java in Android Studio.
I schedule alarms using Alarm Manager and Broadcast Receiver. When I run my program and schedule alarms, no alarms will not appear.BUt it does not show any error.

MainActivity.java

```
final Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, Doritos.class);
    EditText cas = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText datum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    String Datum[] = datum.getText().toString().split(":");
    String Cas[] = cas.getText().toString().split(":");
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(Integer.parseInt(Datum[2]),Integer.parseInt(Datum[1]) - 1,Integer.parseInt(Datum[0]),Integer.parseInt(Cas[0]),Integer.parseInt(Cas[1]),Integer.parseInt(Cas[2]));
    final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    intentAlarm.putExtra("text", text.getText());
    alarmManager.set(alarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, pocet, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Brodcast receiver.java (Doritos.java)

```
public class Doritos extends BroadcastReceiver{

private MainActivity sss = new MainActivity();
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ToneGenerator toneG = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 100);
    toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 200);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_error_outline_black_24dp);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("Nezabudnicek");
    mBuilder.setContentText(intent.getExtras().getCharSequence("text"));
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(sss.pocet,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(sss.pocet, mBuilder.build());
}
```

}

Comment: can you please post the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Manifest. You probably forgot to add broadcast receiver there.
Hope it helps